# How to enable option of scan a new card option in keyboard in Android app compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, credit-card

Recently I observed that in few Android apps on clicking the field of credit card input, there comes an option of "Scan a new card" & after scanning it fills the input field with card details. How can I do it in my app for compose
I have tried using `autoFill` modifier but it didn't work.

```
    autofillTypes: List<AutofillType>,
    onFill: ((String) -> Unit),
) = composed {
    val autofill = LocalAutofill.current
    val autofillNode = AutofillNode(onFill = onFill, autofillTypes = autofillTypes)
    LocalAutofillTree.current += autofillNode

    this.onGloballyPositioned {
        autofillNode.boundingBox = it.boundsInWindow()
    }.onFocusChanged { focusState ->
        autofill?.run {
            if (focusState.isFocused) {
                requestAutofillForNode(autofillNode)
            } else {
                cancelAutofillForNode(autofillNode)
            }
        }
    }
}


Any idea on how can I achieve this ?
Sharing a screenshot of some other where I observed this
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F11cV.jpg
```